# Expected string or buffer django image upload

Tags: python, django

I build my first site with Django and I've faced a problem. When I try to change something in my `models.py` , it throws an error:

```
    Applying Cooking1.0004_recipe_pub_date...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 533, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 27, in handle_noargs
    call_command("migrate", **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 115, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 161, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 68, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 102, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 108, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 37, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 176, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 74, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 187, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 627, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1290, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1269, in get_prep_value
    value = super(DateTimeField, self).get_prep_value(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1171, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1228, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 70, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Specifically, this problem occurs when I try inserting `image` field in `Recipe` model.

Here is my code so far:

**models.py:**

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ingredients = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    cooking_process = models.CharField(max_length=5024)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null= True)
    # pub_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{0}'.format(self.title)
```

**admin.py**:

```
class RecipeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'ingredients', 'cooking_process', 'image')
admin.site.register(Recipe, RecipeAdmin)
```

Comment: Could you give more info about error?

Comment: This is off-topic...but `max_length=5024`...really?? There's a [TextField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField) for this kind of thing.

Comment: What Django version is this? Until recently, a `FileField` or `ImageField` without an `upload_to` was illegal. I know they changed it at some point to allow you to customize the storage instead of using `upload_to`, but you don't seem to have done that either. So… how are you expecting it to accept files?

Comment: Full stack trace would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I've problem with migrations. Version of django - 1.7.Applying Cooking1.0004_recipe_pub_date...Traceback (most recent call last): File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 70, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: I don't know what that last comment means. If you're trying to add information needed to debug your problem, please edit the question, don't try to figure out how to cram it all into a comment. Even if there were enough room in comments, comments lose all formatting, don't show up in searches or summaries, and can even be auto-deleted. If the information isn't in your question, it might as well not be there.